# Drag/Reposition Element On touchmove not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, touch-event

I have a fixed window on my screen that I would like the user to be able to drag around the screen. While I have set this up to work for mouse inputs, I am having more difficulty getting this to work for touch screens.

So I have a basic box like so:

```
<div id="smallavatar" class="smallbox">
</div>
```

Which is then immediately followed by this JS (note that the first half is for the click events)

```
var divOverlay = document.getElementById ("smallavatar");
var isDown = false;
divOverlay.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    isDown = true;
}, true);

document.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
  isDown = false;
}, true);

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   if (isDown) {
   var deltaX = event.movementX;
   var deltaY = event.movementY;
  var rect = divOverlay.getBoundingClientRect();
  divOverlay.style.left = rect.x + deltaX + 'px';
  divOverlay.style.top  = rect.y + deltaY + 'px';
 }
}, true);

divOverlay.addEventListener('touchstart', e => {
  clientX = e.touches[0].screenX;
  clientY = e.touches[0].screenY;
});

divOverlay.addEventListener('touchmove', e => {
  let x =  divOverlay.style.left;
  let y =  divOverlay.style.top;
  // Compute the change in X and Y coordinates. 
  // The first touch point in the changedTouches
  // list is the touch point that was just removed from the surface.
  
  deltaX = e.changedTouches[0].clientX - clientX;
  deltaY = e.changedTouches[0].clientY - clientY;
  
  divOverlay.style.left = divOverlay.style.left + deltaX;
  divOverlay.style.top = divOverlay.style.top + deltaY;
    
});
```

Finally the following CSS is being used:

```
.smallbox{position:fixed; bottom:70px; right:0; width:360px;  height:400px; z-index:20;}
```

Now while the touchmove event does work, the problem is that the box seems to fly off the screen very quickly. The idea is supposed to be that I'm trying to get the position the div was using before the touch event started, then work out how much movement has occured in the touchmove event and then from that update the left and top values with the new position it should be in.

Is there anything wrong that would explain why this isn't working as expected?

Answer (score 1):

You have one major flaw in your code that causes the unexpected result:

- At `touchstart` you store `clientX` and `clientY`, and than during `touchmove` you keep referencing those two values at `deltaX = e.changedTouches[0].clientX - clientX;` (and `Y`).
  But while `e.changedTouches[0].clientX` keeps updating, `clientX` never gets updated and always keeps its initial start-value.
  So for the next frame/iteration, `deltaX = e.changedTouches[0].clientX - clientX;` will actually be the delta-x of that last frame, plus the delta-x of the frame before, and the one before, and before, and so on till the very first frame.
  So your `divOverlay` will be moving exponentially, and be out of sight in a fraction of a sec.
- What the best choice is for getting the current position of `divOverlay`, depends a little on your situation, although I think in most cases, using `pageX`/`pageY` is probably your safest bet.
  The other options are `clientX`/`clientY` and `screenX`/`screenY`, see [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/touch-events/#h3_attributes) and [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch#Properties) for the differences between the three.
  In any case, I wouldn't recommend using them interchangeably during one calculation, unless it's absolutely necessary.

**See the live snippet below for the solution:**

```js
var divOverlay = document.getElementById("smallavatar");

/*MOUSE-LISTENERS---------------------------------------------*/
var isDown=false;
divOverlay.addEventListener('mousedown',function(){isDown=true;},true);
document.addEventListener('mouseup',function(){isDown=false;},true);
document.addEventListener('mousemove',function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (isDown) {
    divOverlay.style.left = divOverlay.offsetLeft + e.movementX + 'px';
    divOverlay.style.top  = divOverlay.offsetTop + e.movementY + 'px';
  }
},true);

/*TOUCH-LISTENERS---------------------------------------------*/
var startX=0, startY=0;
divOverlay.addEventListener('touchstart',function(e) {
  startX = e.changedTouches[0].pageX;
  startY = e.changedTouches[0].pageY;
});

divOverlay.addEventListener('touchmove',function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var deltaX = e.changedTouches[0].pageX - startX;
  var deltaY = e.changedTouches[0].pageY - startY;
  divOverlay.style.left = divOverlay.offsetLeft + deltaX + 'px';
  divOverlay.style.top = divOverlay.offsetTop + deltaY + 'px';
  //reset start-position for next frame/iteration
  startX = e.changedTouches[0].pageX;
  startY = e.changedTouches[0].pageY;
});
```

```css
.smallbox{position:fixed; bottom:70px; right:0; width:36px; height:40px; z-index:20; background:red;}
```

```html
<div id="smallavatar" class="smallbox"></div>
```

***jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2hdczkwn/4/***

- To address your major flaw, I added `startX = e.changedTouches[0].pageX;` and `startY = e.changedTouches[0].pageY;` to the end of your `touchmove` listener, resetting the start-position for each new frame/iteration to the end-position of the last frame/iteration.
- I also added `e.preventDefault();` to your `touchmove` listener, because otherwise any scrollable page would also start scrolling while you were dragging the `divOverlay`.
- I converted your arrow functions into traditional ones, like your mouse listeners.
- I added `var startX=0, startY=0;` outside the functions to make sure they are [global vars](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp).
- I replaced `var rect = divOverlay.getBoundingClientRect();` and `rect.x` and `rect.y` inside your *mousemove* listener, and `divOverlay.style.left` and `divOverlay.style.top` inside your *touchmove* listener, with `divOverlay.offsetLeft` and `divOverlay.offsetTop`.
  This is actually quite important, since `divOverlay.style.left` returns a `px` value, e.g. `57px`. When this value is used in a calculation, like `57px + 12`, it will not result in `69` or `69px` but instead in `NaN`.

I can't help but notice that your mouse and touch listeners are written in a different coding style, *mouse* uses traditional JS, while *touch* is written in the new [ES6](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_es6.asp), using `let` and [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
As if you copied the touch listeners from someone else and didn't change it to match the rest of your code.

While it is fine to use either style and to use other people's code (as long as you have permission), I would discourage using them both in the same project, and it is never a good idea to simply copy someone else's code without rewriting it to fit your own style.
This will make sure your whole project retains its current style of coding, and has the added advantage of you actually understanding the code you're using.

Comment: @DigM I've updated my solution so it actually works:)

Comment: Hey @myfunkyside. if i put it in the parent element it will crash. I wrote the question here. can you help me? thanks in advance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70818875