# Element swipe is wrong when scrolling is greater than 0 in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two elements are the parent-content and child-content when i was scrolled the parent-content element greater than 0 and then i swipe the child-content element it moves very fast. But when I was scrolled to 0 it doesn't fail anymore
how to fix it?

Here is my code:
https://jsfiddle.net/jfu1r0sk/

I'm sorry my English is bad

HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h3 id="display-position">0</h3>
    <div class="parent-content">
        <div class="child-content">
          <h2>Child content</h2>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse lacus lacus, venenatis id gravida pellentesque, molestie vel ipsum. Aenean id magna orci. Integer luctus non nunc ut faucibus. Morbi feugiat blandit elit, sed pellentesque tortor condimentum hendrerit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Quisque magna magna, imperdiet in molestie id, pellentesque at tellus. Pellentesque eros mauris, porta sed posuere eget, volutpat eu neque. Mauris rhoncus tincidunt gravida. Mauris vestibulum mauris vulputate dui sodales suscipit.
        </div>
        <h2>Parent content</h2>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse lacus lacus, venenatis id gravida pellentesque, molestie vel ipsum. Aenean id magna orci. Integer luctus non nunc ut faucibus. Morbi feugiat blandit elit, sed pellentesque tortor condimentum hendrerit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Quisque magna magna, imperdiet in molestie id, pellentesque at tellus. Pellentesque eros mauris, porta sed posuere eget, volutpat eu neque. Mauris rhoncus tincidunt gravida. Mauris vestibulum mauris vulputate dui sodales suscipit.
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS code

```
html {
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  user-select: none;
}

.container {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 600px;
}

.parent-content {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 3px solid blue;
}

.child-content {
  border: 3px solid yellow;
}

#display-position {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: black;
}
```

JavaScript code

```
const container = document.querySelector('.container')
const childContents = document.querySelectorAll('.child-content')
const displayPosition = document.querySelector('#display-position')

childContents.forEach(childContent => {
  /****** TOUCHES ******/
  let startX = 0, startY = 0;
  let screenHeight = window.innerHeight
  
  function handleStart(e) {
    e.stopPropagation()
    e.preventDefault();
    startX = e.touches[0].clientX;
    startY = e.touches[0].clientY;
  }
  
  function handleMove(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation()
    let deltaX = e.touches[0].clientY - startX;
    let deltaY = e.touches[0].clientY - startY;
    let rectContentTop = childContent.getBoundingClientRect().top - childContent.offsetTop
    
    if (deltaY <= -0) {
      childContent.style.transform = `translate3d(0, -${Math.abs(rectContentTop) + Math.abs(deltaY)}px, 0)`;
    } else {
      childContent.style.transform = `translate3d(0, -${Math.abs(rectContentTop) - Math.abs(deltaY)}px, 0)`;
    }
    
    // displayPosition
    // displayPosition.innerHTML = 'Child content ' + deltaY;
    
    // reset frame
    startX = e.touches[0].clientX;
    startY = e.touches[0].clientY;
  }
  
  function handleEnd(e) {}
  
  childContent.addEventListener('touchstart', handleStart);
  childContent.addEventListener('touchmove', handleMove);
  childContent.addEventListener('touchend', handleEnd);
})

container.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  // displayPosition 
    displayPosition.innerHTML = 'Parent scrolling ' + container.scrollTop
})
```